# How does JavaScript object `window.screen.width` detect my ScreenResolution in Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: javascript, screen, width

How does JavaScript object `window.screen.width` detect my ScreenResolution in Firefox under Ubuntu 10.4?

I mean what it accesses in OS to retrieve this data - OS variable or OS config files like  a) .xprofile, b) kdm/gdm, c) xorg.conf. ?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly an implementation detail that could vary from one user-agent (browser) to another.

Comment: @SWT: I wrote it's FireFox. Any idea ?

Comment: sorry, overlooked that.  Unfortunately, I don't have a clue--but FireFox *is* open-source, if you have some time to do some digging ;-)